# PHP application not working on Glassfish + Quertus server

Tags: php, codeigniter, glassfish

I have an PHP application (codeigniter framework) and I'm forced to migrate it to a Glassfish Server. I configured it and installed the Quercus PHP interpreter into it. Simple test pages works fine. But my PHP app has some errors:

```
Message: 'num_rows' is an unknown method of false.
Filename: core/Loader.php 
Line number: 1099
```

I think the Quercus is not able to interpret some Codeigniter functions.

More info:
Glassfish 4.1 running on Ubuntu 15.04, 
Quercus 4.0.35, 
Codeigniter 2.1.12.

Comment: Was it working application before migration or you are making it from scratch?

Comment: The application works fine on PHP Apache server